# How to download all header files in the link given?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, download, header-files

I want to download all the files under this directory
[link containing .h and .c files](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/)

How can I download all files in one go? as a tar file or any other format with the same hierarchy structure of files?

Comment: Why don't you just go to the [glibc homepage](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), where you can find links to download the actual source archives and from them get all the files you need?

Comment: and there are tons of download managers capable of parsing the links for downloads by some pattern. Not a programming question anyway.

Comment: You can also just contact us and we can provide you with a file system image of the glibs subdirectory. Alternatively use the code browser generator to create this directory yourself https://github.com/woboq/woboq_codebrowser